# Landau's Theorem Proof - Raghavan Narasimhan's Complex Analysis in One Variable

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]
[image]
[image]

I don't understand what is the conclusion of Landau's Theorem proof. How I get the conclusion from the last line of the proof?

Comment: choose $R(\alpha)=(2/\lambda(\alpha))^{1/2}$; the proof shows that if $f$ is as above and $f$ misses both $0,1$ then $R \le  R(\alpha)$ so by contrapositive, if $R >R(\alpha)$ then $f$ as above must take $0$ or $1$ or both

Comment: I understood now! Thank you very much!!!